# I have a sidebar with toggle menu but it don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-5

I have a sidebar in my cPanel, And this sidebar has a menu toggle.
for example ==>
When clicking on the 'Account setting' there are some links or options under it.
[image]

And this is my code

```
 <li class="menu-item">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="menu-link menu-toggle">
        <i class="menu-icon tf-icons bx bx-dock-top"></i>
        <div data-i18n="Account Settings">Account Settings</div>
      </a>
      <ul class="menu-sub">
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="pages-account-settings-account.html" class="menu-link">
            <div data-i18n="Account">Account</div>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
          <a href="pages-account-settings-notifications.html" class="menu-link">
            <div data-i18n="Notifications">Notifications</div>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
```

Note : I'm working in Angular 14

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz for this piece of code?

Comment: @RhettHarrison No I dont!

Comment: Would you mind making one? It'd be easier for myself and others to actually play around with the code and figure out the issue. I believe I can figure it out, but I am not seeing it right away

Comment: @RhettHarrison Yes, Of course, I will sir.

Comment: @RhettHarrison http://stackblitz.com/github/MohanedGhawar2019/UserManagementApp